# java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format using Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, keytool

On enabling ssl mode in Tomcat 7, I'm getting the following error on my tomcat logs

I have genrated .key file using openssl like below

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out localhost 2048
```

And I given the path to my key file in tomcat server.xml

> SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-bio-8443"] java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`openssl genrsa -des3 -out localhost 2048` generates a private key. What you need to run a web server using HTTPS is a private key and a certificate. You'll need a step to generate a certificate.

You can configure HTTPS in Tomcat using 2 almost completely different approaches, depending on whether you're using the APR connector or not.

If you're using the [APR connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/apr.html#HTTP/HTTPS), it makes sense to use OpenSSL to generate the keys/certificate, since it's the format it expects. (There are a number of tutorials to generate self-signed certificates with OpenSSL, if a self-signed certificate is sufficient for your environment.)

[If you're not using APR](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html), you would have to convert the keys/cert generated with OpenSSL into a keystore format supported by your JRE. Coming from OpenSSL, converting your private key + certificate into a PKCS#12 store (`.p12`) is usually the easiest: this is supported directly via Oracle/OpenJDK with the `PKCS12` keystore type. (You could convert your PKCS#12 file into a JKS store, but that's not necessary.)

However, if you don't have any keys/cert yet, the easiest way to generate a self-signed certificate for Tomcat is to use `keytool` directly. This will produce a `JKS` keystore, which is the default type. [`keytool -genkey`](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/GeneratingSelfSignedCertificateWithKeytool) not only generates a key/pair and enough to produce a CSR, but it associates a self-signed certificate (at least temporarily until you import the certificate coming from a CA if necessary).

Answer (score -2):

Java based systems, including tomcat, need stores in the PKCS format. So, first you need to build your stores correctly and then follow the tomcat guide to configure tomcat to use them. Your store format and the configuration do not seem to be correct.

Comment: That's not true. Firstly, it depends whether you're using APR or not. Secondly, the default keystore type is still JKS. In principle, any keystore type supported by one of the security providers can be used, so it depends on the providers. On Oracle/OpenJDK (with the Sun providers), you can use JKS, PKCS#12, PKCS#11 and NSS.