# Invalid keystore format: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Tags: java, security, jboss, keytool, der

I have generated the certificate from the below command

```
Openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tls.key -out tls.crt -subj "/CN=nginxsvc/O=nginxsvc"
```

and then in client machine import like this

```
keytool -import -file C:\Code_Base\Certificates\NGINX_150\tls.crt -storepass changeit -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -alias nginxsvc
```

and in Standalone.xml file of Jboss server added

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
                <ssl name="ssl" password="changeit" certificate-key-file="C:\Code_Base\Certificates\NGINX_150\tls.key"/>
</connector>
```

But when server starting i am getting

> 11:12:17,279 ERROR [org.apache.tomcat.util] (MSC service thread 1-3)
>   JBWEB003003: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path
>   C:\Code_Base\Certificates\NGINX_150\tls.key due to Invalid keystore
>   format: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format  at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:350)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:265)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:480)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:417)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:180)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:973)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:174)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:986)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:318)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]    at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980)
>   [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913)
>   [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]
>
> 11:12:17,283 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC
>   service thread 1-3) JBWEB003043: Error initializing endpoint:
>   java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format  at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:350)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:265)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:480)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:417)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:180)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:973)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:174)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:986)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:318)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]    at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980)
>   [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913)
>   [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]
>
> 11:12:17,289 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC
>   service thread 1-2) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on :
>   http-/0.0.0.0:8080 11:12:17,297 INFO 
>   [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2)
>   JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-/0.0.0.0:8080
>   11:12:17,311 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
>   1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.connector.https:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.web.connector.https: JBAS018007: Error starting web connector
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:393)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980)
>   [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913)
>   [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_152] Caused by: LifecycleException:  JBWEB000023:
>   Protocol handler initialization failed    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:989)  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:318)
>     ... 5 more

Comment: [java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format using Tomcat server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10071081/608639), [Tomcat 7 and invalid keystore format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33196674/608639) and friends

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to consider is the mismatch of keystore types.

You may check the keystore type of your existing keystore as follows:

```
 keytool -list -keystore <path/to/keystore>
```

This should display the Keystore type value in the output like

> Keystore type: PKCS12

This may be different to the default keystore type (**JKS** in your case) that it is expecting

If so, use the appropriate keystoreType attribute in your tomcat server configuration to match your key store

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreType="PKCS12"
           keystoreFile="path/to/keystore" keystorePass="changeit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Run keytool with store type param:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -storetype JKS
```